# how to add the button clicks and count in a dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, count, nsmutabledictionary

I have a method called `addbuttonClicktocounter`. When the function is called it should add the button name as key and number of clicks as count. I made this in my static library. When the user called these method again and again it should capture all the button names and number of clicks in one dictionary. If same button clicks again and again means the button name should remain same and the click count oly get increased. Here is my code what my tried upto my level:

```
NSMutableDictionary *BtnclicDict;

-(void) addButtonClickToCounter : (NSString*)button_Name button_click :(int)but_Click{
    if([[BtnclicDict allKeys] containsObject:button_Name]){
        int saveClick = [[BtnclicDict valueForKey:button_Name] integerValue];
        but_Click = saveClick + but_Click;

        NSNumber *click = [NSNumber numberWithInt:but_Click];
        NSString *clickString = [click stringValue];

        [BtnclicDict setObject:clickString forKey:button_Name];
        NSLog(@"same button...,%@",click);
        NSLog(@"same key dict...,%@",BtnclicDict);
    } else {
        NSString *but_Name = [NSString stringWithString:button_Name];
        // NSLog(@"%@",but_Name);
        NSNumber *click = [NSNumber numberWithInt:but_Click];
        //  NSLog(@"%@",click);
        NSString *clickString = [click stringValue];

        // BtnclicDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:but_Name forKey:click];
        // BtnclicDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [BtnclicDict setObject:clickString forKey:but_Name];
        NSLog(@"working,%@",BtnclicDict);
        //   NSLog(@"%@ Button Values...",BtnclicDict);
    }
}
```

If you call this method from another class again and again it should collect all the details and make it into one dictionary.

Comment: What problem are you having with the posted code?

Comment: BTW - all of this will be *much* easier is you simply use an `NSCountedSet` instead of an `NSMutableDictionary`.

Comment: if my button is same i have to add the recent count with the existing count..  Example :  [addButtonClickToCounter : @"scan" : 2]   [addButtonClickToCounter : @"scan" : 3]   [addButtonClickToCounter : @"update" : 3]   [addButtonClickToCounter : @"scan" : 5] .. for this my result should be {"scan": "10","update":"3" }..  i made it.. same button count is not correct.. Check the code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this.

```
-(void) addButtonClickToCounter : (NSString*)button_Name button_click :(int)but_Click{   
    if ([BtnclicDict valueForKey:buttonName])
        but_Click += [[BtnclicDict valueForKey:button_Name] integerValue];
    [BtnclicDict setValue:but_Click forKey:button_Name];
}
```